# iframe touch event preventDefault

Tags: javascript, iframe, mobile, touch

I am writing some mobile code and want to stop the window from being moved by the user's touch. Normally I use something like

`$(window).bind('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); } );`

However, an iFrame on the HTML body will not adhere to the behavior of this event!

I know that the cross-domain origin policy does not allow me to mess with the body inside of the iframe, and I don't want to have to do any server-side caching to serve content. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

do you try

```
$("iframeSelector").contents().find("body").bind(...)
```